# Расстояние между словами в css

Tags: css

Есть список, который превращается в горизонтальное меню.
Превращается он хорошо, но мне нужны большие отступы между словами.

`word-spacing` не работает, только `padding`.

Проблема в том, что справа и слева тоже вставляются отступы, то есть слова "*Главная*" и "*Карта сайта*" отходят от крайних границ. Как можно исправить?

```css
.bottom_menu { 
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.bottom_menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 12px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom_menu">
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">карта сайта</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: В общем, добавил к левому крайнему и правому крайнему тегу <li> идентификатор и через него поставил padding(left-right соответственно) ноль. C левой стороны сработало, с правой пока нет. Но проблема, вроде как, решается этим способом. Может быть, у кого-то есть более элегантное решение? Напишу сразу, что justify не подходит))

Comment: Откатывать верный и подробный ответ и ставить на другой не красиво так поступать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляйте padding, а потом li:nth-last-child{padding:0}, ну и по аналогии для первого элемента

Comment: да, вот это вообще отлично работает, спасибо! Правда, запись срабатывала только такого вида: nth-child (1)

Comment: @ArturMark, вы приняли ответ с кодом, который ошибочно написан, и решает проблему только наполовину, `:nth-last-child` редко используется для того чтобы выбрать последний элементы списка, а первый тем более, для этого есть другие псевдоклассы, которые изначально были в моём примере.

Answer (score 4):

Задать отступы между ссылками можно так `padding-right: 30px`

Запретить перенос строки можно так `white-space: nowrap`

Отступы между словами задаются так `word-spacing: 20px` в родительском элементе. Но тогда и ссылка *карта__сайта* будет иметь отступ

Вместо `padding` можно указать `margin-left: 30px` с `float: left`

Убрать отступ у последнего элемента в списке можно в html через атрибут style
`<li style='padding-right: 0'><a href="/">карта сайта</a></li>`

или в css, используя псевдокласс `:last-child`

```css
.bottom_menu { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    // word-spacing: 20px;
}

.bottom_menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: verdana;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
  
  padding-right: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bottom_menu li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom_menu">
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">карта сайта</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не особо понял что нужно автору, может это? Чтобы растянуть меню на всю ширину страницы нужно добавить `display: table; width: 100%`, а чтобы убрать у первого и у последнего элементов отступы нужно добавить псевдоклассы `:first-child` и `:last-child` с нужными paddind, это сделано в примере ниже:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.bottom_menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.bottom_menu li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: verdana;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bottom_menu li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.bottom_menu li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom_menu">
  <li><a href="/">главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">главная</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/">карта сайта</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Между пунктами меню нужен большой пробел. Он добавляется с помощью padding. Но padding так же добавляет этот самый пробел и с краев и получается, что меню не justify, a center)) В общем вот http://s019.radikal.ru/i604/1606/57/20667115869f.jpg - видите, справа и слева меню не прилегает к краю

Comment: Сделал вплотную